# Default timezone for DateTime deserialization with Jackson (Joda-Time module)

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, deserialization, jodatime

This question is about deserialization to **[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)** using [jackson-datatype-joda module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) for **Jackson**. Is there a default timezone that date strings will be deserialized into? If so, what is it? Is it *[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)*?

I need to ask this because the Jackson documentation is not specific for Joda-Time DateTime. I found in this article (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling) that Jackson will assume *[GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)* as the default time zone for deserializing into `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`. However, there is no mention of Joda-Time data types in this document. In addition, I specifically need strings to deserialize into `DateTime` objects using the *UTC* timezone, not GMT: although these two zones are very similar, there are some small differences and therefore GMT will not be feasible for me.

Thank you.

Comment: UTC & GMT are virtually identical for most purposes. What specifically makes you draw a distinction in your app?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The source code for [`DateTimeDeserializer`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/DateTimeDeserializer.java) shows it uses the timezone from `DeserializationContext` which is provided by `ObjectMapper` during deserialization. If you look at [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) API, you will see there is method for setting the timezone:

```
public ObjectMapper setTimeZone(TimeZone tz)
```

Thus you can use this method to configure your `ObjectMapper` and set the timezone to the correct one.

For what concerns the default value, it seems the Javadoc says one thing, but the code shows another.

Javadoc for `ObjectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone tz)`:

```
/**
  * Method for overriding default TimeZone to use for formatting.
  * Default value used is {@link TimeZone#getDefault()}.
  */
```

However, the code sets the timezone explicitly on:

```
protected final static BaseSettings DEFAULT_BASE = new BaseSettings(
    ...
    // TimeZone.getDefault()
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
    ...
```

So, apparently, it actually uses GMT, and not the default JVM default.

I would say that probably the best choice would be not relying on this and set it by yourself on `ObjectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone tz)`.

Comment: The default setting of GMT is exactly what I'm looking for. Looks like Java doesn't use "UTC" as a possible TimeZone. Thank you.

Comment: So this is bug in Jackson implementation? Should we create new ticket?

Answer (score 17):

### UTC versus GMT

For business apps, there is no practical difference between [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMT). The only difference relates to sub-second resolution and a [Leap Second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) added every several years. For science, astronomy, satellite-tracking, and such apps the difference may be significant, but that's rare.

### Jackson Defaults to UTC/GMT

I don't know *Jackson*. But from looking at the doc you linked, it looks like they serialize either (a) the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, UTC, or (b) a string format, the default being [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000". So, to answer your question about time zones, it sounds like by default Jackson always serializes using UTC (no time zone offset) which is the right way to do it. If you care about the time zone that was in use at that time, you should record that fact (what time zone) in a separate field.

### Jackson ↔ java.util.Date/Calendar ↔ Joda-Time

Both of those serialized values (milliseconds & ISO 8601 string) can be used with constructors for Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instances.

```java
String dateTimeString = "2013-11-22T18:37:55.645+0000";
org.joda.time.DateTime myDateTime = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( dateTimeString );
```

and…

```java
Long millisSinceEpoch = 1385495462L;
org.joda.time.DateTime myDateTime = new org.joda.time.DateTime( millisSinceEpoch );
```

If you do not have direct access to those serialized values to feed to Joda-Time DateTime constructors, then let Jackson instantiate java.util.Date/Calendar objects. Feed those java.util.Date/Calendar objects to Joda-Time to instantiate DateTime objects for further work. Joda-Time users do this commonly.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTime myDateTime = new org.joda.time.DateTime( someJavaUtilDateFromJackson );
```

You can easily convert that UTC time to other time zones in Joda-Time by calling the [toDateTime()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toDateTime%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) method and passing the desired time zone.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone kolkataTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeInKolkata = myDateTime.toDateTime( kolkataTimeZone );
```

Joda-Time easily converts back to java.util.Date using the [toDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate%28%29) method. So do most of your work in Joda-Time, and convert back to java.util.Date to communicate with Jackson. And when going back to Jackson, I would switch my DateTimes back to UTC just for good measure.

```java
myDateTime.toDateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC )
```

You’ll find many examples of the aforementioned Joda-Time operations here on StackOverflow.com.

### Just Do It

I suspect you are doing a little too much worrying and not enough coding. Just try a few little experiments passing values in and out of Jackson and Joda-Time. You'll quickly get the hang of it. I recommend you let Jackson do whatever it wants to do by default, then manipulate away in Joda-Time. Joda-Time is built for the gnarly problems of date-time, and Jackson is presumably not. Joda-Time has both constructors and methods to adjust between time zones as desired.

### A Brighter Future

In Java 8, [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) brings Joda-Time-like classes built into the Java platform. Expect to see frameworks like *Jackson* updated to directly work with those new classes while deprecating the ugly java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

It looks like that [jackson-datatype-joda project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) is trying to bring you that kind of convenience now for Joda-Time. But it does not seem necessary to me. You could just convert between java.util.Date/Calendar and Joda-Time as discussed above.

P.S. The "Wiki" link for that project's documentation fails. So I could not look at their doc.

Answer (score 8):

I also struggled with date formats and finally I found solution. I wanted to use format `"2016-02-08T12:49:22.876Z"` since it is ISO 8601 and it is used by JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. I also wanted to always use UTC time zone.

I found that this can be done using following code:

```java
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Date()));
```

Please note the `X` character in format string. It is supported from Java 7 and specifies time zone in ISO 8601. As documented in [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) it produces `Z` (instead of `+00:00`) if time zone offset is 0 (UTC).

Answer (score 1):

From a simple code I found that when Jackson deserialize to Date object from string it gives UTC if no timezone is mentioned but when instantiated directly then [gives default timezone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) i.e. the timezone of the machine.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0) //gives local timezone
```

Following gives UTC

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0);
String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(dt);
DateTime dt1 = mapper.readValue(serialized, DateTime.class); //gives UTC
```