# Jackson Joda Module deserialize ISO Date to Joda DateTime

Tags: java, spring, datetime, jackson, jodatime

I'm using Spring to retrieve JSON data from a Web API rest API, with the Jackson Joda Module to deserialize an ISO date, and convert it into a Joda `DateTime`.

Spring request:

```
HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    final ResponseEntity<returnedEntities> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, EntitiesList.class);
```

The Entities have a property that is a Joda `DateTime`

```
/**
 *
 * @return
 * The departureDate
 */
@JsonProperty("departureDate")
public DateTime getDepartureDate() {
    return departureDate;
}

/**
 *
 * @param departureDate
 * The departureDate
 */
@JsonProperty("departureDate")
public void setDepartureDate(DateTime departureDate) {
    this.departureDate = departureDate;
}
```

My problem is the servers returning JSON with a local time like so:

> "departureDate": "2017-10-03T00:00:00+01:00",

So the above represents 3rd of October the `+01` representing that we're in British Summer time 1 hour ahead of GMT.

Now Jackson JSON Module appears to be stripping the timezone information effectively converting the time into a GMT datetime.
And so the Joda `DateTime` returned is:

> 2017-10-02T23:00:00.000Z

The 2nd of October at 11pm, which is the wrong date.

What do I need to do to have the Jackson Joda Module store the `+1:00` timezone when converting the Json to the Joda `DateTime`?

At present I have a vanilla Joda Module:

```
JodaModule jodaModule = new JodaModule();
jsonConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(jodaModule);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(jodaModule);

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(jodaModule);

objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);           
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
listHttpMessageConverters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deserializing, by default, Jackson adjusts the dates to the [context timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20227224/7605325). In your case, it's adjusting it to UTC (`2017-10-03T00:00:00+01:00` is equivalent to `2017-10-02T23:00:00.000Z` - the `Z` in the end of the `String` is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)).

To avoid this and preserve the input's timezone, you can disable the [`ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE):

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
```

With this, an input `String` such as `2017-10-03T00:00:00+01:00` will be deserialized to a Joda's `DateTime` with the value `2017-10-03T00:00:00.000+01:00`.

Comment: You've just saved a considerable amount of hair loss :)
Thanks works perfectly!